# my google play uninstall by itself.. how can i install it again ?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung

I have just reset my Samsung Galaxy Ace and now Google Play doesn't shown up. I've already restarted my phone but nothing happens, and I've downloaded a different Play Store but it doesn't seem to open.  Before I reset my phone I read that nothing will be un-installed from my application, but how does it come that Google Play doesn't shown up ?

Answer (score -1):

Here http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/02/22/download-latest-google-play-store-3-10-14/ you will find download links to the play store in this site